# Why blender splits my imported model in pieces?

Tags: import, collada

I created a model in Sketch-Up (Sketch-Up detects it as a solid, a closed hull, where all faces can be seen from outside).
Then i exported it as Collada  .dae.
But Blender splits 5 faces off and converts them into separate objects, each one out of two faces, one face lies flat on the other one.

[This is the link to the original-sketchup-object](https://www.sketchup-forum.de/attachment.php?aid=1413)

This is the model in Blender. Main part moved to set the separated objects :

[image: model in Blender. main part moved to set the separated objects free]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Your link to the original sketchup is pretty much useless, since you need to be logged in to download it. Please provide a converted file that can be imported into blender directly and can be downloaded by everyone without the need of an account.

Comment: i don´t know how to upload a .dae-file.

Answer (score 1):

Well its pretty unusual workflow, so dont aspect everything to work.
however maybe blender can save your day
make sure to join all loose objects  (border select on screen and join them).

Next in edit mode try verticles remove doubles.. if your lucky itss all connected afterwards
next recalculate normals.

Comment: i can better draw my stuff in Sketchup, but need it in blender to turn it into building-blocks for a game, called "space-engineers"

Comment: I can't find verticles remove doubles?